# SNMP Trap Listener throws exception nullReferenceException

Tags: c#, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I am creating an SNMP Trap Listener using SNMP Library in c#. I used the following code to receive traps

```
try
        {
            lst = new Listener();
            lst.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162));  
            lst.MessageReceived += Listener_MessageReceived;
            lst.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {      
        }   
private static void Listener_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // SNMP trap recived Here.
        File.AppendAllText("c:/temp/servicelog.log", "Version :" + e.Message.Version + "\n");
        File.AppendAllText("c:/temp/servicelog.log", "Version :" + e.Message.Scope.Pdu.Variables[4].Data.ToString() + "\n");
       
    }
```

I run this as a service and then I send trpas using Trap Simulator. The following is the output I got in log file.

- HandleMessage :Enter.
  HandleMessage System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.ISnmpMessage]Version :V2*

When I debug it  got following error
[image]

I also get the following [image]

Comment: What sequence is it fialing?  See : https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/ch02_03.htm?force_isolation=true

Comment: You should get started from the official sample, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmptrapd not your random code.

Comment: I used this sample code, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/snmp-trap-listener-using-snmp-library/